# On upgrade to manic minotaur 23.10, python threading deamon not working

Tags: upgrade, python

I upgraded Ubuntu from 23.04 to 23.10

Release 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) 64-bit

Kernel Linux 6.5.0-17-generic x86_64

Python3 version 3.11.6

Since upgrading, any python programs using threading with deamon = True not longer kill the thread once the python script is finished.

Here is a simple script to prove the point:

```
import threading as th

def thread_method():
    input()
thread_test = th.Thread(target=thread_method, args=(), name='daemon_exit_test', daemon=True)
thread_test.start()
print(thread_test.isDaemon())

print('print this then exit')
```

This creates a deamon thread, and holds it waiting for an input(), i.e. enter key.

In the past, because the flag deamon=True, as soon as it reaches the end of the script it will kill the thread. Now it does not behave like that, and holds the thread open, which can be ended manually by pushing the enter key to accept the input().

I tried in a python 3.9 and a python 3.12 environment, same issue.

Is there a setting in the Ubuntu 23.10 to get this working per usual? Maybe a kernel switch or upgrade?

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug, even if there is some workaround. You can report it with `ubuntu-bug python3` and follow the prompts. You can also check with a slightly older version of Python on your current system to see if it's a python issue or a linux issue.

Comment: It is intended behavior that `input()` blocks the whole process. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914294/10477326  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23081060/10477326 . You can put a `time.sleep(1)` before the `input()` and see that it quits as expected

Comment: @DanielT very interesting, on my system this exits immediately.

Comment: @Esther thanks I'll try the bug report, sounds like the best approach. I tried now in python 3.9 and 3.12, same issue. You mention is works for you, may I ask which kernel version you are using?

Comment: @Esther It only happens on 23.10 (both my tablet and Docker ubuntu:mantic). It doesn't happen on 22.04 and 23.04. Docker means same kernel